# django websites and google

Tags: django, web-development, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I have recently finished one of my side projects. Now many sites have things like robot.txts (probably not the best file to describe what i need but you get what I mean)  and things of that nature not totally sure what else there is but things behind the scenes that sites use to identify themselves to things like google, yahoo, and bing(but I could have just said google! zing!)

I was wondering, what I needed to add to my site for it to be fully web compliant and searchable and proper. I am basically looking for best practices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what rolling stone said, you should check [Django's sitemap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sitemaps/).